# In Wordpress, how do you make several different editors for a single page?

Tags: php, cms

I have a homepage that has many different parts to it. So a s single editor can get convoluted very quickly.

Is there a way to break it up so that many editors attribute to this single page?

If so, what's your technique?

Comment: Technique: Google.

Comment: Hakre, I will poo on your html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you should use this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/magic-fields/

It will enable you to specify any kind of content for a given post or page. This new version already uses wordpress custom post types.